# Why Does the Size of my EF Model Greatly Affect Query Performance?

Tags: entity-framework

Using EF 6.1 database first with model.  Without respect to the merits or demerits of having scoped models, I'd like to know what is going on.  If I run the exact same query on a model that only contains the entities/tables in my query compared to a model that contains all entities/tables (assuming lazy loading is turned off) both queries should take the same time to execute.

Logically the only difference should be that the model/object with the ability to query all entities will have the additional overhead of all the code to deal with all entities.  A heavier class, but it shouldn't affect query performance.

Here is the query:

```
        using ( var context = new MyEntities() )
        {
            context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            var parentIds = new List<int> { 1, 2 };
            var entities = ( from e in context.Entities.Include( "SomeRelatedEntity" )
                             join eParent in context.Parents on e.ParentId equals eParent.Id
                             where parentIds.Contains( eParent.Id )
                             select e )
                            .ToList();
        }
```

Using the full model, this takes over 2X as long to get 80K entities.  When run against the full model, upon executing the line with ToList, it sits there for 10 seconds before ever hitting the database!

If I add a call to .AsNoTracking() after each entity set, the lag goes away.

If I run the same query with the same large model using reverse engineered code first it takes yet a whole lot more time.  This, no doubt, is due to tracking proxy generation (at least it makes sense).

Why is EF taking this long to perform a query of tracked entities?  Is there something I can do to speed it up?  How can this not be a bug (there isn't any DBMS whereby existing queries are penalized by the addition of new tables)?

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you see that performance hit every time you run the query, on only the first time?

Comment: Good question.  Of course the very same query takes little time the next time it's called, but a different query does the same thing; eternity before actually hitting the DB.

Comment: Could it be due to [view generation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469601)?

Comment: Good suggestion, but made no difference.  I suspect this view generation time is small; executing the option via power tools was instantaneous.